# What is the Regex to Search a XML tag and remove comma from the value in a notepad++

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++

The xml Tag is in a xml document

XML Doc:

```
<Root>
<Parent>
.
.
<ABC>1,543</ABC>
.
.
</Parent>
</Root>
```

Output:

```
<Root>
<Parent>
.
.
<ABC>1543</ABC>
.
.
</Parent>
</Root>
```

What is the regex which I should run in a XML Editor or Notepad ++ which will give me the output ie remove comma from that specific tag

The xml is huge like this 
    
    
    .
    .
    1,543
    .
    .
    

    .
    .
    1,543
    .
    .
    

    .
    .
    1,543
    .
    .
    

    .
    .
    1,543
    .
    .
    

    .
    .
    1,543
    .
    .

What is the best way to do it

Comment: Is there only one comma for each tag?

Comment: Yes the amounts are in thousand only and there is only one comma. Can you list any unix command or notepad ++ Find and replace regex which would do that. The xml is huge like this <Root>
<Parent>
.
.
<ABC>1,543</ABC>
.
.
</Parent>
</Root>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have only one comma, search for:

```
(<ABC>.*)[,](.*</ABC>)
```

Replace with:

```
$1$2
```

If you have multiple commas, you'll have to run it multiple times.  If the tags are broken up with new lines (\r\n or just \n) you'll have to incorporate those into the regex.

Note that if your XML is on a single line, this regex could have unintended consequences, matching

```
<ABC>123</ABC><AnotherTagWhereCommasAreOk>,</AnotherTagWhereCommasAreOk><ABC>456</ABC>
```

And replacing the comma in the different tag.

For a truly robust solution, you'd probably want to use XSLT.  Regexes will only get you so far with trivial cases in XML.  The template would contain something along the lines of

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Root/Parent/ABC">
  <xsl:if test="contains(., ',')">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(., ','), substring-after(.,',') />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

You create a template and run it using XML Tools in Notepad++

Comment: If there is no comma between one of these tags, it may remove a comma everywhere in the file.

Comment: Could you clarify that?  I'm testing it now with and without commas and it works.  The only issue is that if there are multiple commas it will have to be run repeatedly.

Comment: @DanField He means that this will match `<ABC>foo</ABC>,<ABC>bar</ABC>`.

Comment: Ok, but the OP had all elements separated out on new lines so that sequence shouldn't occur

Comment: Fair enough. Should work unless the editor has `.` match newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this regex `>(\d+),(\d+)<`, and then replace it with this `>$1$2<`. Considering there is only one comma inside each tag.

Comment: This would replace commas in all tags - the post asked how to remove one from a specific tag.

Comment: Oh ya, didn't see it. I guess your answer will do. ;)